# how to change body text ontap of a listview.builder item while im using map<>

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know how can i make items in a list view builder clickable so i can change text in the body (outside list view builder) because I am using a map<> data

```
 ListView.builder(
 itemCount: values.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    String key = values.keys.elementAt(index);
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new ListTile(
          title: new Text("$key"),
          subtitle: new Text("${values[key]}"),
        ),
        new Divider(
          height: 2.0,
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

`new Text("${values[key]}")`, i want to use this on body and change the text when i click on specific item .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to keep track on changes
1* declare variable
var myVar = "";

2* Edit your code

```
ListView.builder(
     itemCount: values.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        String key = values.keys.elementAt(index);
        return new GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
             setState((){myVar = values[key]});},
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text("$key"),
              subtitle: new Text("${values[key]}"),
            ),
            new Divider(
              height: 2.0,
            ),
          ],
        ));
      },
    );
```

3* Then on body you can use it like this

```
Text(myVar)
```